# File not found system error when entering into a function

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, unhandled-exception, file-not-found

While running some code I am getting a unhanded exception for file not found with no file location or file name specified. If I break I can see the function that the error is being reported from. I can reach break points before where that function is called but can't enter into the function with out the exception being thrown. The function is in the same class and C# code file. There were issues with references to other projects in the past with this project. Could it an issue of scope or delayed loading because of calls made from with in the function?

Visual Studio 2008, C#

Any ideas welcome, Answers wanted.

Comment: I have seen this type of thing happen when ActiveX registration goes awry.

Comment: If you can break at the moment the exception is being thrown, you have all the information you need right in front of you. Just go to the frame that throws and see why it throws. If the code editor debugger wanna be doesn't cooperate, use a real debugger like Windbg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look to see if fuslogvw is complaining about any missing assemblies

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Sysinternals. It can give you loads of useful information about a running process, including all file access attemps.

Comment: I've seen this many times when an unmanaged dependency is missing.  When will microsoft fill in the file exception info properly?